# How to debug grunt (gruntfile)?

Tags: debugging, gruntjs, gruntfile

I have a gruntfile with few tasks configured. Some of the use functions like:

```
middleware: (connect, options, defaultMiddleware) =>
                    proxy = require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest;
                    window.alert proxy
                    return [proxy].concat(defaultMiddleware)
```

I wanted to use alerts or console.log to be able to debug this but whenever I try to run grunt it tells me "alert is not defined", "console is not defined".

How else am I able to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

node-inspector could help you better on this.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-inspector